# NSDateFormatter set date from twitter-timeline to (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, nsdateformatter

I want to add the posting date to my twitter timeline in a tableView. I use the date from "created_at" and want to transform it by the NSDateFormatter. The problem is, as on the logs visible, I have the correct twitter date (Datum), the correct actual system date (actual date) and after the formatter the actual date is formatted correct (control after formatter) but the date of the twitter timeline is after the formatter (null). Why? What can or better must I change to solve that?

```
NSDate *Datum = d[@"created_at"];
NSString *Tweet = t[@"text"];
UIImage *Bild = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tweet-timeline.png"];

NSLog(@"Content of Datum: %@", Datum);

NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd.mm.yyyy"];
[dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateformatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];


NSString *test = [dateformatter stringFromDate:Datum];
NSString *control = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Content of Datum after Formatter: %@", test);
NSLog(@"Content of actual date: %@", [NSDate date]);
NSLog(@"Content of control after Formatter: %@", control);
```

And the logs:

[image]

Comment: You probably can't trust `NSLog(@"Content of Datum: %@", Datum);` as that will output the date in the GMT timezone.  Use a dateformatter to log it and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the error.

After reading again the help of STTwitter I had to "preformat" the date as explained there:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter st_TwitterDateFormatter];
NSString *dateString = [d valueForKey:@"created_at"]; // "Sun Jun 28 20:33:01 +0000 2009"
NSDate *rohdatum = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

And with this "rohdatum" (rawdate) my dateformatter works perfect.